# HTML, CSS - центровка и грамотный перенос текста

Tags: html, css

[image: №1]

[image: №2]

Как добиться того, чтобы текст был ровно по центру и при переносе (когда меняю разрешение браузера) не перекрывал сам себя? Спасибо!!!

```css
.mbanner{
    width:100%;
    height:75vh;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


.mbanner .ghtext{
    position:relative;
 top:50%;
}

.mbanner .ghtext .title1 {
 height:17%;
 font-family:"hoefler";
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:77px;
 color:#fff; 
}

.mbanner .ghtext .title2 {

 font-family:"lato";
 font-weight:300;
 font-size:40px;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="mbanner" style="background-image:url(http://unicnecosorio.cnec.br/wp-content/uploads/sites/133/2017/05/Ci%C3%AAncias-Cont%C3%A1beis.jpg)">
 <div class="ghtext">
  <div class="title1">Respect Consulting Group </div>
  <div class="title2">at service of your objectives.</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://take.ms/9xDF6Z 
1) Картинку пришлось искать в интернете. Т.к. твоя картинка не отображается.
2) Предоставленный тобой код работает как у меня на скриншоте (ссылка вверху).
3) Советую посмотреть в инспекторе где какие свойства перекрывают друг-друга или предоставить больше кода.
* выделил текст т.к. на светлом фоне не видно белые буквы. окно браузера уменьшал и увеличивал - все гуд.

Comment: Почему-то здесь переносится, а у меня в браузере не хочет. А как отцентровать текст?

Comment: Используй центрирование через inline-block.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо! Разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mbanner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.mbanner .ghtext {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
}

.mbanner .ghtext .title1 {
  font-family: "hoefler";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 77px;
  color: #fff;
}

.mbanner .ghtext .title2 {
  font-family: "lato";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="mbanner" style="background-image:url(http://unicnecosorio.cnec.br/wp-content/uploads/sites/133/2017/05/Ci%C3%AAncias-Cont%C3%A1beis.jpg)">
  <div class="ghtext">
    <div class="title1">Respect Consulting Group </div>
    <div class="title2">at service of your objectives.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```